# Issues with Products after Data Migration

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce

Following my Woocommerce site's data migration to a new hosting provider, I seem to have a few issues with my product - seems like a potential issue with the database.
To fix it, I simply have to open the Product and click Update without making any changes seems to fix the issue. I have tried the BULK Edit option and siply clicking Save, but that does not help and requires me to open each products using Edit and then Update.

I tried the following script found on another post but that did not help either.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'update_products_by_x' );
function update_products_by_x(){
    $limit = 200;

    // getting all products
    $products_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        => 'product','product_variation',
        'numberposts'      => $limit,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array( array(
            'key'     => '_sync_updated',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ) )
    ) );

    // Loop through product Ids
    foreach ( $products_ids as $product_id ) {

        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        // Mark product as updated
        $product->update_meta_data( '_sync_updated', true );

        $product->save();
    }
}
```

After Exporting the products into a CSV file - which has products which have been fixed and some which haven't been fixed, I see the following:

Meta: _a3_pvc_activated  - Fixed shows FALSE and Not Fixed shows `<blank>`
Meta: _monsterinsights_sitenote_active - Fixed shows 0 and NOT Fixed shows `<blank>`
Meta: _wpas_skip_publicize_24800780 - Fixed shows 1 and NOT Fixed shows `<blank>`
Meta: _wpas_skip_publicize_25101066 - Fixed shows 1 and NOT Fixed shows `<blank>`

There may be other issues like linking the product to the database, but one of the ways to see which products are working and which not, have a look at the following search link

https://crawleycoins.co.uk/?product_cat=1-circulated&s=&post_type=product

Only 4 products are listed, but on the right, you can see that this category has 12 products.
One workarond for seach is to simply remove &s= and then u can see all 12 of them so they are certainly categorised correctly but something is just not linked up correctly and I cannot seem to find a way to fix this.